# How to get old/previous Value which entered in input text field with onchange() event in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield

How to get old/previous Value  which entered in input text field with onchange() event in LWC ? please help

Answer (score 3):

The [change event spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) doesn't account for an old value so you will need to keep track of the value within the component by writing the old or original value to a component property and then referencing it in your change handler. You could also keep an array or a stack of values if you needed a history of what the values were set to.

```js
oldValue;

handleChange(event) {
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    // compare oldValue to newValue here
}
```